# AWS failed build package-lock.json missing files

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm following the tutorial here to deploy a Full stack app to AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/

In the deployment stage, my build is failing with a log that says I'm missing files.
I'm following their tutorial to a T, I asked a similar question before and found out the `package-lock.json` file was missing things, but didn't care for the reason and just copied a `package-lock.json` file that worked.
However, after continuing the tutorial, the problem returned so now I wish to know why this happens.

The commands I use in Visual Studio Code:

`npx create-react-app amplifyapp`

`cd amplifyapp`

`git init`

`git remote add origin https://github.com/AsafO7/amplify-react-graphql.git`

`git branch -M main`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "initial commit"`

`git push -u origin main`

This is the Github repo: https://github.com/AsafO7/amplify-react-graphql

This is the error log:

```
 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                                    npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.9.5 from lock file
                                    npm
2023-03-05T15:37:00.201Z [WARNING]: ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
2023-03-05T15:37:00.201Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Clean install a project
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Usage:
                                    npm ERR! npm ci
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Options:
                                    npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
                                    npm
2023-03-05T15:37:00.203Z [WARNING]: ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
                                    npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
                                    npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
                                    npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
                                    npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
                                    npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
                                    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-05T15_36_57_362Z-debug-0.log
2023-03-05T15:37:00.208Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-03-05T15:37:00.208Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-03-05T15:37:00.208Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-03-05T15:37:00.208Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

I tried `npm install` and pushing to the repo but nothing changed.
The person who helped me before followed the same tutorial and it worked for them so I don't know what is wrong here...

EDIT:
After deleting the `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder and running `npm i` on the CLI, I don't get missing files errors anymore, but I do get this error log:

```
                           ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
            npm ERR! Clean install a project
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Usage:
                                    npm ERR! npm ci
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Options:
                                    npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
                                    npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
                                    npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
                                    npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
                                    npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
                                    npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
                                    npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
                                    npm
2023-03-06T10:57:53.792Z [WARNING]: ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-06T10_57_50_838Z-debug-0.log
2023-03-06T10:57:53.798Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-03-06T10:57:53.799Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-03-06T10:57:53.799Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-03-06T10:57:53.799Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Anything I can do to solve it?

Comment: Delete your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and run `npm i` in the `CLI` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you. I no longer get missing files errors, but I edited the post with the new error log I'm getting...
Do you know why I was missing files in the first place?

Comment: Can you try with cloud9? it appears to me that your local dev setup seems to be causing some issues. use a cloud9 with 4GB RAM and 2 cores.

Comment: Hello again Sri.
I tried your suggestion and unfortunately I got the same error as the one in the edit.

Comment: I would create a new folder, and pull your backend into it. You can find the command to pull the environment in the console. Then make one small change, and push. This'll help you isolate the introduced issue. That is, if you've managed to create the `env`.

Comment: But, there's no backend?
It's just `npx create-react-app` that was pushed to a Github repo and then was supposed to be deployed into AWS Amplify but failed to do so.
Did I miss something?

Comment: @asaf, any chance you can provide the history of commands that you were running from the start?

Comment: @Sri Yes, I provided them at the top of the post.

Comment: @asaf, I did some investigation. the commands are all fine. I did a deploy of my own repo from the tutorial and your repo. The reason why it failed was because of `npm ERR! npm ci can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with npm install before continuing` so I forked your repo, ran `npm install` (without deleting anything) and pushed the changes and it worked https://main.d3o16pl4l9otpt.amplifyapp.com/. Repo at https://github.com/kasukur/amplify-react-graphql-asaf

Comment: I don't know what to say... I did the same thing and got the second error log on my post...
So I'm assuming the problem is on my machine, but I've no idea what it is...